# Kohana 3.1 orm. How to make this has_one relashionship?

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm

I have 2 models: `Address` and `Country`. Now, every address has exactly one country. So `Address` model has:

```
protected $_has_one = array('country' => array(
    'model' => 'Country',
    'foreign_key' => 'code',
));
```

I load `Address` object:

```
$addr = ORM::factory('Address', 1);
$country = $addr->country->find();
```

But `$country` always contains first record instead of a related record from the `Country` table.
Am I doing something wrong here? If yes, what's the correct way?

**EDIT:**
table `Country` has PK `code` and no FK.
table `Address` has PK `id` and FK `country_code`

Comment: 1 address has exactly one country and 1 country belongs to many addresses is `one-to-many` relation, not `one-to-one`

Comment: But `Country` cannot belongs to anything as it's only utility table with all known countries and is referenced from many other tables.

Comment: as long as one country belongs to any number of addresses - it is `one-to-many` relation. rtfm

Comment: you're right. I've edited the subject.

Comment: Use `$addr->country` (without `find()`).

Answer (score 4):

Your has_one property should be as follows:

```
protected $_has_one = array('country' => array(
  'model' => 'Country',
  'foreign_key' => 'country_code',
));
```

Foreign key is the key in your table of the current model that links to the primary key of the related model.